# When will an electron fired at a proton be captured instead of scattered?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy-conservation, scattering, hydrogen

Suppose electrons of energy $E>0$ are fired toward a proton. Since energy is always conserved in a central motion, and because an electron bound to a hydrogen atom must have negative energy $(E<0)$, is it ever possible for electrons with energy $E>0$ to get captured by the proton (forming a hydrogen atom)? I am not sure. It seems to me that unless there is a mechanism (radiation damping or something else) by which the electrons can lose energy, they cannot get captured by the proton. If electrons shot with energy $E>0$ do indeed get captured, I think that would mean it must have lost some energy.

Am I right about the condition of capture? If so, is this reasoning on the right track?

Comment: Electrons gain and lose energy by emitting or absorbing photons. This is how they are able to transfer energy-levels within an atom/molecule, and it's how energy conservation is maintained when they are captured in the first place. The reverse of this can be seen in laser-ionization: high energy photons accelerate the electron completely out of their stable orbit around a proton.

Comment: @Matteo When an electron with energy $E>0$ is fired at a proton, can it get captured? If you give me an answer (i.e. 'yes' or 'no'), I can explain the doubt better. :-)

Comment: Yes, it can. It conserves energy by emitting a photon.

Comment: Aha! So I was on the right track. A free electron of positive energy ($E>0$) can be captured by a proton only if it emits a photon and in that process loses some energy to settle into a bound state of negative energy ($E<0$). Did I summarize it correctly?

Comment: Indeed! Though it's important to note that the negative energy of a bound electron is a choice of convention. Just like the height of a mountain, it is only ever a metric which is relative to a baseline, and in this case negative energies are chosen because of the fact that it would take adding energy $E$ to the electron to have it be in free state. The main thing to notice, and the physically absolute quantity, is the energy difference $\Delta E$ between the starting free electron and the ending bound electron. That $\Delta E$ will be the exact energy of the photon released.